# trying to split a url into an array like http:,www.,stackoverflow,questions,ask

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, url

the input works fine and it will output the string ok but i am so bad at creating arrays and I just don't know what to do after that I have looked everywhere and have not found a way to do it.

```
            <body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Url:
        </legend>
        <input type="url" ID="inputurl" value="please input a URL"> 
        <input type="button" onclick="PlaceUrl()" value="try me">

</fieldset>
</form>
<p id="URLdemo"></p>

<script>

    function PlaceUrl() {
        var x = document.getElementById("inputurl").value;
        document.getElementById("URLdemo").innerHTML = x;
         //outputs the string fine
        var x = string.split(window.location.pathname);
        var x = str.array (window.location.pathname.split(x));
        //this does nothing
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Please add more details about what you're trying to accomplish. You say it will "output the string ok", but what exactly are you getting stuck on now?

Comment: i need the string to convert to an array depending on what website the person put into the input. i just used stackoverflow and an example it could be any url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483624/trying-to-split-a-url-into-an-array-like-http-www-stackoverflow-questions-ask'
var arr = href.split(/[\.\\\/]/g)
console.log(arr)

// ["https:", "", "stackoverflow", "com", "questions", "59483624", "trying-to-split-a-url-into-an-array-like-http-www-stackoverflow-questions-ask"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor to work with it.

`window.location` points to the current window/tab you're working with. That means: You cannot work with stackoverflow.com on the site example.com via `window.location`. You can use `URL()` instead.

```js
var url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483624/trying-to-split-a-url-into-an-array-like-http-www-stackoverflow-questions-ask#');

console.log('Host:', url.host);
console.log('Path name:', url.pathname);
console.log('Question id:', url.pathname.split('/')[2]);
console.log('Question title:', url.pathname.split('/')[3]);
```

Comment: this doesn't take what was input tho it just uses this url